# Data not fully retrieved while using mgo pipe function

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I was using pipe function in mgo to retrieve data. My data structs are as follows.

```
type Company struct {
    Id              bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    CompanyName     string
    Slug            string
    CompanyUsers    []CompanyUser
}
type CompanyUser    struct {
    UserName    string
    Email       string
    FullName    string
}
```

I needed to check whether a given "UserName" is present under "CompanyUsers" in a "Company" with a given "Slug".

Both Slug and UserName are provided by the User.

Using Pipe function I successfully done the search, but the data is returned with an empty CompanyUsers array.

My query is as follows:

```
var companyResults []Company

pipeline := []bson.M{
    {"$match": bson.M{"slug": slug}},
    {"$unwind": "$companyusers"},
    {"$match": bson.M{
        "companyusers.username": username,
    }},
}
err := c.Pipe(pipeline).All(&companyResults)
```

This provides me a search result as follows:

```
[{ObjectIdHex("573aa0fddd731711c94830ca") MyCompany companyslug [] }]
```

None of the data in CompanyUsers are retrieved. How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try making `companyResults` a `[]map[string]interface{}` instead of a `[]Company` to see what sort of a result you get. This helps to figure out what the structure of `companyResults` should be.

```
var companyResults []map[string]interface{}
```

You will see a result like,

```
[map[companyname:MyCompany slug:companyslug companyusers:map[username:username] _id:test]]
```

See that `companyusers` is infact a map not an array. This is because your usage of the `$unwind` stage. It deconstructs the array, outputting one document for each element in the array. See [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).

I agree with John Smith's answer, that you do not need pipelines at all. But following should give you the desired result.

```
type Result struct {
    Id           string `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    CompanyName  string
    Slug         string
    CompanyUsers CompanyUser
}

var companyResults []Result
```

Answer (score 3):

I might be missing something, but why do you need `Pipe` for this?

You probably could do it easier:

```
query := bson.M{"slug": slug, "companyusers.username": username}

err := c.Find(query).All(&companyResults)
```

I'm fairly certain this would give you the same results.

However, **the main problem** is you didn't give the bson marshaller the fields name. Since the field in your database is `companyusers` and `username` you'll have to tell that to the marshaller.

```
type Company struct {
    Id              bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    CompanyName     string
    Slug            string
    CompanyUsers    []CompanyUser `bson:"companyuser"`
}
type CompanyUser    struct {
    UserName    string `bson:"username"`
    Email       string
    FullName    string
}
```

You probably want to fix that for the rest of the fields as well.

Comment: is it necessary to add bson marshaller? I was able to do mgo queries so far without them. Are there any chances of danger for my already written queries?

Comment: In your case it's probably not, but I would still rather do it. It's not much of an additional typing, but could help later on.